# MAVEN dependency failed

Tags: maven

Please see below I am not able to run maven project on eclipse

- 1) downloaded eclipse
- 2) downloaded MAVEN repository
- 3) set env variable M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME, JAVA_HOME
- 4) SET path to maven bin folder

and `mvn -version` is working fine

in below case its failed to update maven while running from cmd please help

```
C:\Users\sridhar.m> mvn eclipse:eclipse
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on
e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 o
r one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
```

Comment: Your formatting was far to be easy to read, please check if the reformatting I applied is consistent with what you had in mind

Comment: That sounds like a proxy problem.

Comment: I recommend to use a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus rather than accessing Maven Central (or other repositories) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied your settings.xml to your .m2 folder (your M2_HOME)?

Also have you set your proxy correctly (in the settings.xml) so your maven can get out to the internet?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be you didn't configure the installation of your Maven in Eclipse 
You have to go in Eclispe -> Window -> Preferences -> Maven and choose the `Installations` and add the path of your repository Maven and **NOT** let the **EMBEDDED** folder .

If it's not working you maybe have a problem of proxy so you have to configure it in the file `setting.xml` Under `Path to Maven\conf\setting.xml`

GL.